# anonymous function in matlab executable

Tags: matlab, executable, anonymous-function

I have a three files that work perfectly before I compile them. However when I compile them matlab behaves as if I didn't include one of the files even though it is included in the deployment.

```
function testMain

kuzu = zeros(5,1);
anonymousFunction = testClass.anonymousFunction;
kuzu2 = anonymousFunction(kuzu)

end

classdef testClass
    properties (Constant)
        anonymousFunction = @(x) replaceZeroWithNaN2(x)
    end
end

function output = replaceZeroWithNaN2(input)

input(input==0) = NaN;
output = input;

end
```

All the files are in the same directory. After compilation I get the following error:

Undefined function 'replaceZeroWithNaN2' for input arguments of type 'double'

Answer (score 1):

The following is from [MATLAB's guide on code generation (from ver. 2011b)](http://cda.psych.uiuc.edu/matlab_programming_class_2012/eml_ug.pdf):
[image: Unsupported Code Features]

Clearly your use of the anonymous function is causing issues.

It's possible that this has changed in the time since this guide was published, but I would be a bit surprised. Try reworking your code to avoid anonymous function calls; you'll probably save a bit of overhead anyway.

#### Edit:

After a bit more digging [I found here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/matlab-language-features-supported-for-code-generation.html) that MATLAB now supports objects, however, anonymous functions are still unsupported.

Comment: -1 This answer is not relevant. The documentation you include is from MATLAB Coder, used for generating C code from MATLAB. OP is not doing this, but deploying code as an executable using MATLAB Compiler, an entirely different product that has none of the restrictions on the language subset that you mention.

Answer (score 1):

When MATLAB Compiler packages your code into an executable, it needs to include all the files that your main function depends on. It does this using dependency analysis, i.e. walking through the code to see which things it depends on, and which things those things depend on.

Sometimes the dependency analysis can fail and it misses some dependencies. For example, if your code calls something like `eval('myfunction')`, it won't find `myfunction` as a dependency.

It looks like, for whatever reason, the dependency analysis is not finding `replaceZeroWithNaN2`, and it's not getting included in your executable, so you're getting the error you see. You can check this yourself by running `depfun('testMain.m')` - `depfun` is the command MATLAB uses to find dependencies, and the output shows that it's finding the dependency on `testClass`, but not `replaceZeroWithNaN2`.

In cases like this you can explicitly tell the dependency analysis to include a function.

Put the following comment at the top of `testClass.m`:

```
%#function replaceZeroWithNaN2
```

The `%#function` is a *pragma* that explicitly tells the dependency analysis that the code below depends on the function `replaceZeroWithNaN2`. When I do that, the output of `depfun` now includes `replaceZeroWithNaN2`.

MATLAB Compiler should then include `replaceZeroWithNaN2` and your executable should work.

You might also like to report the issue to MathWorks: it feels to me like the dependency analysis really should be picking up `replaceZeroWithNaN2` already, and it's maybe a bug.

Comment: %#function expression seems to solve my problem without making major changes in my code. Thanks!